# grep multiple patterns with different context

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

I have a file roughly like

```
header_one
param1
param2
...

data_one
data1
data2
data3
data4
...

header_two
param1
param2
...

data_two
data1
data2
data3
data4
```

I'd like to extract all `header` blocks with `N` following lines and all `data` blocks with `M != N` following lines, keeping the order in which they appear in the file and discarding everything else.

If `M == N == 8` I could e.g. do

```
grep -A8 -E "header_|data_"
```

But what if I want to have different context for each pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ad-hoc solution with awk could be something like this:

```
awk '/^header_/ {n=1+1} /^data_/ {n=1+2} n-- > 0; n == 0 {print "---"}' < file
```

`n` is set on matching lines, and is decremented for each line. The lines are printed when `n` is positive with a separator after each block. With the above values, it would print `header_` lines plus one next line, and `data_` lines plus two next lines.

---

If the context blocks can overlap, the new value of `n` will override the previous value. To prevent that, add conditions to guard the assignments:

```
awk '/^header_/ {if (n < 2) n=2} 
     /^data_/   {if (n < 5) n=5}
     n-- > 0; n == 0 {print "---"}' < file
```

That should be better at handling cases where there's `data_` and `header_` on consecutive lines.

Comment: amazing, and also easy to extend to more complex parsing... I should definitely study `awk` sooner than later

Comment: @filippo, well, the "after" context is easy... the "before" context is more work since it needs remembering past input. And even trickier if the blocks can overlap.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried with below sed command  As tested it worked fine let me know for any confusions

```
sed -n -e  '/header_/,+1p' -e '/^data_/,+2p' filename
```

output

```
header_one
param1
data_one
data1
data2
header_two
param1
data_two
data1
data2
```

Comment: One difference from grep is handling overlapping matches.  Say if `data_one` immediately followed `header_one`, it would be printed twice — once as part of `/header_/,+1` address range, once as part of `/^data_/,+2` range.

Comment: Numbering the lines with `cat filename | nl | sed -n -e  '/\theader_/,+1p' -e '/\tdata_/,+2p'` helps figure out where lines were skipped (and where they're printed twice)...